# Can't change int to str implicitly

Tags: python, string, int, typeerror

I'm trying to create a program that will ask the user to input the year Haley's comet was last seen, then add 75 and 76 years to that, then output the result.

```
lastsight = int(input("When was the last sighting? "))
firstsight = lastsight + 75 
secondsight = lastsight + 76
print("The next sighting will be in", firstsight,  "or", secondsight + ".")
```

However, whenever I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "program.py", line 5, in <module>
print("The next sighting will be in", firstsight,  "or", secondsight + ".")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Any help on how I can fix it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
print("The next sighting will be in", firstsight,  "or", str(secondsight) + ".")
```

As you correctly observed, python does not perform these conversions implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print("The next sighting will be in {} or {}.".format(firstsight,  secondsight))
```